"Invalid deployment ID" error while setting configuration of Google Chat API
I am trying to create a google chat app but I am getting "Invalid deployment ID" error
I am trying to create a google chat app and publishing using the instructions written in https://developers.google.com/workspace/chat/quickstart/apps-script-app but during the configuration of Chat API, it returns invalid Deployment Id. I am not sure what I am missing out but I have done exactly what's being said.
Is there any missing part in the instructions that have been assumed to be done already?
Thanks

What deployment type are you using?
The script deployment portion is likely incomplete in the instructions.
You should be using web app type and, notably to create a test deployment of a web app, you need to actually deploy it first.
So, try deploying (not test) as a web app and you might as well use the head deployment id, or use the test deployment after deploying.


yes, i did. I guess, I am missing out on something in the Google Cloud setting.

Hi Martin, I have retried, this time it worked. i am not sure what I did wrong in the first place. Thanks anyway.
